# Paths in the graph topology induced on a graph.

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Given a planar directed graph $G = (V,E)$, we can induce the graph topology $G'$ by replacing each vertex with a point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and each edge with a copy of the unit interval $[0,1]$. Is there a convenient way to do this while also maintaining a sense of the directions of the graph? Specifically, is there a way to formally define paths in the graph topology $G'$ that respect the directions of the original graph? Normally we can define a path in a topological space as a map $f:[0,1] \rightarrow G'$, but that definition doesn't take into account the directions of a directed topological space.

Comment: My differential topology is a little too weak to formulate this properly, but if you're willing to throw out rough paths then you could ask for the derivative of the path on the edges to have a specified "sign." In any case, my intuition is to bake the orientation into the path rather than the topology itself. There are notions of asymmetric metrics which might be closer to what you want, though?

Comment: Maybe instead of the euclidean topology on each edge, use the [Sorgenfrey topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000043)?

Comment: @EricNathanStucky I haven't learned any differential topology at all, just algebraic topology. The orientation needs to be a part of the topology because I'm developing a generalization of Kripke frames, which necessarily are built off of digraphs

Comment: @StevenClontz I'm not sure how that would help preserve the notion of direction; could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the question based on the comments, specifically "the orientation needs to be part of the topology" - if the goal is to have a definition of direction that depends only on the topology then that's impossible, since you could always reverse all the edges and get the same topology on $G'$.  (If you don't need the orientation to be induced by the topology, then I guess you just define relation $aR b$ if $a$ and $b$ lie on a directed edge with $a$ preceding $b$, then look at that relation's transitive closure $\leq$, then define paths as ones that respect $\leq$.)

Comment: Or maybe my last comment is being obtuse, wasn't clear whether you were allowing different topologies than the usual graph topology, if so then of course you might be able to define one that includes direction.

Comment: @MW Let me try to rephrase. Suppose we have a set of vertices $V$, along with an "accessibility relation" $R$ on $V.$ We draw a directed edge from $v_1$ to $v_2$ if and only if $v_1 R v_2$. From this, we get a directed graph $(V,E)$. On an undirected graph, we can induce a graph topology. I'm looking for a way to induce a graph topology on a directed graph, such that the induced topology preserves the sense of direction, and especially such that we can talk about paths in the topology which respect direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pitch, though I haven't worked out details. EDIT: A crucial shortcoming has been pointed out by MW in the comments.

One way to get the graph topology on an undirected graph $G=\langle V,E\rangle$ is to consider the topological space $[0,1]\times E$, then take the quotient where $(i_0,e_0)\sim(i_1,e_1)$ provided $i_0,i_1\in\{0,1\}$ and $e_0(i_0)=e_1(i_1)$ (where $e(0),e(1)$ designate the two endpoints of $e$). Then the paths of the graph $G$ correspond to the continuous functions $p:[0,1]\to X$ where $p(0)$ is the starting vertex and $p(1)$ is the ending vertex.

So perhaps one way to get a topological interpretation of the directed graph $D=\langle V,E\rangle$ is to consider the topological space $[0,1]_s\times E$, where $[0,1]_s$ has basic open sets of the form $[x,x+\epsilon)$. Then we again take the quotient where $(i_0,e_0)\sim(i_1,e_1)$ provided $i_0,i_1\in\{0,1\}$ and $e_0(i_0)=e_1(i_1)$ (where $e(0),e(1)$ designate the starting and ending endpoints of $e$, respectively). Then the paths of the graph $G$ correspond to the continuous functions $p:[0,1]_s\to X$ where $p(0)$ is the starting vertex and $p(1)$ is the ending vertex. Note here that continuity is only allowed when the directions are honored: in particular, $f:[0,1]_s\to[0,1]_s$ defined by $f(t)=1-t$ traces the edge backwards, and is not continuous: given a basic open neighborhood $[x,x+\epsilon)$ in $[0,1]_s$, its inverse image $f^\leftarrow[[x,x+\epsilon)]=(1-x-\epsilon,1-x]$ is not open in $[0,1]_s$.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, though there are some maps that would be continuous that might not be desirable paths, e.g., path that takes $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ to $[0,\frac{1}{3})$ and $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ to $[\frac{2}{3},1]$, piecewise linearly.

Comment: Ah-ha, that's a good catch. We lose connectedness, and I think that spells doom for this approach: as long as any vertex has an out-edge, and another vertex has an in-edge, we can create a "path" using this approach.

Comment: I suppose a bitopological result requiring that the same function be continuous with respect to *both* the Sorgenfrey and Euclidean topologies might patch this up, but it's no longer feeling as elegant a solution as I'd hoped.

Answer (score 0):

There is one approach I can think of that requires the graph to be acyclic (in the sense of having no *directed* cycles), and even then has some serious shortcomings, but I'll describe it anyway in case it is of some use.

First define a partial order on $G'$ in the intuitive way, namely, define a relation $R$ on $G'$ by $aRb$ if $a$ and $b$ lie on a directed edge with $a$ before $b$ relative to that direction.  Then let $\leq$ be that relation's transitive closure.

Next, on any partially ordered set $(P,\leq)$, you can define a topology wherein the open sets are those sets $U$ for which $a\in U$ and $b\geq a$ implies $b\in U$.
Given two such posets $P$ and $Q$ with this topology, if $P$ is totally ordered, we can see that a map $f\colon P\to Q$ is continuous if and only if it is (not necessarily strictly) increasing, i.e., $f(a)\leq f(b)$ whenever $a\leq b$.

To see this, in one direction suppose $f$ is continuous, then for $a\leq b$, we have  $f^{-1}(\{y\in Q\mid y\not \leq f(b)\})$ does not contain $b$, hence by open-ness it does not contain $a$, so we have $f(a)\leq f(b)$.

Conversely, if $f$ is increasing, then for $U$ open, if $a\in f^{-1}(U)$ and $a\leq b$, then since $f(a)\in U$ and $f(b)\geq f(a)$ we have $f(b)\in U$, so $b\in f^{-1}(U)$, implying $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Therefore if you give your directed acyclic graph the above topology, and give the same topology to $[0,1]$, then the continuous paths are precisely the functions from $[0,1]$ to $G'$ which respect the order.

While these paths will not necessarily be continuous under the usual Euclidean and  graph topologies, they will have only countably many discontinuities, and will never reverse course.

##### Remark

I haven't checked this in detail, but I *think* that if you instead define a sub-basis of open sets for $P$ as those of the form $\{x\in P\mid x\not\leq a\}$ for $a\in P$, then your continuous paths from $[0,1]$ should be exactly those order-respecting maps that are continuous from the left in the usual topologies.